# what's the difference difference between phantom.exit and .close in phantom.js?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

If I'm doing web scraping using phantom.js to click some buttons and links what's the convenient one to terminate program with ?

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/close.html
http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/exit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS `.exit()` is a core method of *phantom Object* and you can use it to quit the phantomjs program instance (like Nodejs process.exit).
This is the convenient method to terminate your program.

```
console.log('Quitting Phantomjs');
phantom.exit();
```

`.close()` method is part of *Web Page Module* and is used to close a web page.

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://github.com', function (status) {
  if (status === "success") {
    // do stuff
    page.close();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** `.close()` clears memory, `.exit()` may not.

`.close()` belongs to phantomjs' webpage.
`.exit()` belongs to phantomjs process itself.

If you do a lot of automated tasks, opening pages and not closing them -
 this can cause memory leak.

So preferred way to terminate is to 1. close the page and 2. exit phantom after that.